# What leads the first element of a printed list to be enclosed with backticks in R v3.5.1?

Tags: r

Recently I updated R to 3.5.1 on may Windows 10 with RStudio v1.1.453. I am interested why the first element of a printed list is now always enclosed in backticks? Even if it is a standard name without illegal symbols, e.g., `` `a` `` as in this example:

```
# R 3.5.1
list(a = 1, b = 2, g = 9)
#> $`a`
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $g
#> [1] 9
```

In previous versions of R, the result looked like this:

```
# R 3.4.4
list(a = 1, b = 2, g = 9)
#> $a
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> $g
#> [1] 9
```

Do these additional backticks have some meaning? Is it some kind of advancement? Or is it a side effect of some other R functionality? A drawback?

Comment: I tried on a R console and Rstudio (1.1453) on (R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
)but couldn't reproduce the behavior, probably a windows issue `dput(list(a = 1, b = 2, g = 9))
list(a = 1, b = 2, g = 9)`

Comment: @akrun, can you reproduce [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51343335/4783029)?

Comment: Seems like the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387825/unnecessary-backticks-in-r, although there's no real answer there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unnecessary backticks in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387825/unnecessary-backticks-in-r)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is [a bug in R 3.5.1 only on Windows](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16101). It has been fixed in r-devel [as of 17 August 2018](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2018-August/076630.html).

Comment: When is the fixed version of **R** going to be released? Will it be a patch v3.5.2 which will be released in a few months or is it going to be v3.6.0 and will be released the next year only?

Comment: Probably 3.5.2, I would guess.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem here and have used the workaround:

```
foo = list('asdf'=NA) # Dummy initial entry
for (listname in c('a','b','c')){
  foo[[listname]] = 1
}
```